# Add a link to extension resource in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I want to add link tags to the head so I can preload some font files in my site package.

I have tried using `headerData` but how can I get file path to `EXT:my_site/Resources`?

Comment: Please post the complete code snippet of what you tried already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For any field in TypoScript that uses the `getText` data type, you can use `path:` for that. For example:

```
page.headerData.123 = TEXT
page.headerData.123.data = path:EXT:extension/Resources/Public/path/to/file
page.headerData.123.wrap = <tag property="|">
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/DataTypes/#path for more information.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I was looking all over for that. On a side note, do you know if there is a way to move `headerData` above `includeCSS`?

Comment: I've never tried, but I think the only way to do that is to overwrite `page.pageHeaderFooterTemplateFile` with a custom template file. You can find the default file in typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRenderer.html